# Is it legal to write a new JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, virtual

Suppose that someone writes a commercial Java Virtual Machine for windows according to current java bytecode standard. Is it legal? Will Oracle sue the author?

Comment: Can Wirte. But they must get licensee from Oracle to publish it. *IMHO*

Comment: Oracle even have a verification system to ensure that your JVM is 100% compatible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: The question is about a mix of legal and technical topics. At first I wanted to post in patents section but I thought it might be off-topic there

Comment: There's a whole bunch of alternate JVMs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines

Comment: @mahdix The only question you've asked is whether you would get sued. There's nothing technical about that, except to a lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR it is perfectly legal to write you own JVM, but I don't think you are allowed to call it Java-compatible unless you pass the tests in the [TCK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit) - which has a more restrictive license.

To get a feel for the legal issues involved see the history of the [Apache Harmony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Harmony) project.

Comment: So it seems that it is legal to commercially distribute this piece of software without calling it a certified JVM.

Comment: Sure, take a look at the GNU CLASSPATH project for another example. Nothing like Java, not claimed to be, no TCK, nothing. Useless piece of junk, but apparently legal.